# does opencv flann library support integer data?

Tags: opencv

Hi I am trying to do nearest neighbor queries on integer data. 
It seems that cv::flann does not support this. Is this true?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to use FLANN nearest neighbor searches on integer data. You need to use a distance measure for integers. Some distance measures are templates, parameterized on data type (as in the example below), others have hard coded types (e.g. `HammingLUT` has `unsigned char` element type and `int` result (distance) type). You can also implement your own distance measure, see `<opencv2/flann/dist.h>` for details.

Example - a quote from the code that uses `unsigned char` data:

```
// we use euclidean distances on unsigned chars:
typedef cv::flann::L2<unsigned char> Distance_U8;
cv::flann::GenericIndex< Distance_U8 > * m_flann;

// ...
// we have 3d features
cv::Mat features( features_count, 3, CV_8UC1 );

// ... fill the features matrix ...

// ... build the index ...
m_flann = new cv::flann::GenericIndex< Distance_U8 > (features, params);

// ... 

// how many neighbours per query?
in knn = 5;
// search params - see documentation
cvflann::SearchParams params;

// prepare the matrices
// query data - unsigned chars, 3d (like features)
cv::Mat input_1( n_pixels, 3, CV_8UC1 ),
        // indices into features array - integers
        indices_1( n_pixels, knn, CV_32S ),
        // distances - floats (even with integer data distances are floats)
        dists_1( n_pixels, knn, CV_32F );

m_flann->knnSearch( input_1, indices_1, dists_1, 1, params);
```

Comment: Hi @artm - where is this code sample taken from? Is ip open source? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was just looking for an example like this.

Comment: that project used a mix of Qt and OpenCV, could be a bit messy to learn from, but it worked as recently as Oct 2012 (tested on linux mint and Mac OSX) :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, FLANN is for float descriptors only. Although poorly documented the OpenCV set of matchers and descriptors must be used carefully.

There is a [bug report on the ros trac](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/978) explaining in more detail, but basically descriptors and matchers only handle certain types of data, and this must be respected. I've included an extract from the previously mentioned page here for reference:

> Descriptors:
> float descriptors: SIFT, SURF
> uchar descriptors: ORB BRIEF
>
> Matchers:
> for float descriptor: FlannBased BruteForce BruteForce-L1
> for uchar descriptor: BruteForce-Hamming BruteForce-HammingLUT